# How to install pkg_add in a fresh OpenBSD 5.8 installation?

Tags: openbsd

I installed OpenBSD into a Virtualbox using the install58.iso and installing all sets.
Now I want to install more packages via pkg_add which is not in the users nor roots path.
How do I get pkg_add? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know what shell you are using, but this is in the default PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/[user]/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/games:.
$ which pkg_add
/usr/sbin/pkg_add
```

Comment: I reinstalled the VM in the mean time and have it in the path now, too. Thanks for your time, though.